# Update the WPF UI while processing - best use of async await

Tags: wpf, async-await, task-parallel-library

Here is what i have tried - It works, as far as seeing the UI refreshed, but i don't think it's the best use of async / await. How can i improve on this?

```
private async void btnQuickTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlReader reader;
    int rowCount = 0;
    using (reader = XmlReader.Create("someXmlFile.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rowCount++;

            DoSomeProcessingOnTheUIThread(reader);

            //only update UI every 100 loops
            if (rowCount > 0 && rowCount % 100 == 0)
            {
                //yay! release the UI thread
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        () =>
                        {
                            txtRowCount.Text = string.Format("{0}", rowCount);
                        });
                });
            }

        } //end-while
    }//end-using
}
```

What's a better approach?

**UPDATE:**
I have avoided the Dispatcher.Invoke based on the answer of Clemens, by sending the processing to a background task, and updating progress on the UI directly.
My code now looks like.

```
private async void btnQuickTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    XmlReader reader;
    int rowCount = 0;
    using (reader = XmlReader.Create("someXmlFile.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rowCount++;

            await DoSomeProcessing(reader);

            //only update UI every 100 loops
            if (rowCount % 100 == 0)
            {
                txtRowCount.Text = string.Format("{0}", rowCount);
            }

        } //end-while
    }//end-using
    MessageBox.Show("I am done!");
}

private Task DoSomeProcessing(XmlReader reader)
{
   Task t =Task.Run(() =>
   {
       //Do my processing here.
   });
   return t;
}
```

**UPDATE#2:**
On reflection, why am i creating a new Task on every loop ?
It would probably be better to just run the whole loop within one background task. And periodically raise a callback to show progress; See my other answer below.

Comment: If your code works, but you want someone to suggest improvements, you might want to ask this question on Code Review instead.

Comment: Shouldnt you do "some processing" on a NON-UI thread?

Comment: What does DoSomeProcessingOnTheUIThread do?

Comment: DoSomeProcessingOnTheUIThread()  is just some processing which i have to do on the XML file; i.e. the "meat" of what i am trying to process, I was being lazy, and trying to avoid callbacks to the UI thread to notify of progress.

Comment: Your updated code looks good. ps. Minor thing, It's custom to end the name of methods run asynchronously with "Async"; await DoSomeProcessingAsync().

Comment: So all this is required because "UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" doesn't actually perform the update when the property changes as the name would suggest. Perhaps a more meaningful name is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Task that immediately calls `Dispatcher.Invoke` is pointless, because there is nothing that actually runs on a background thread, except the tiny piece of code that schedules the Dispatcher action.

Better set the Text property directly, and use `XmlReader.ReadAsync`:

```
private async void btnQuickTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("someXmlFile.xml"))
    {
        int rowCount = 0;

        while (await reader.ReadAsync())
        {
            rowCount++;

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DoSomeWork(reader);
            });

            if (rowCount > 0 && rowCount % 100 == 0)
            {
                txtRowCount.Text = string.Format("{0}", rowCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You may also consider making your `DoSomeWork` async and directly call it like this:

```
await DoSomeWork(reader);
```

Comment: I don't see how .ReadAsync() will help me; I want to keep reading the file and process the records in it, and periodically show progress on the UI without blocking it (or have the rowcount go from 0 to complete). But your second idea of awaiting the processing part helped me.  So i changed it so that no Dispatcher is required - updated my question, but you deserve the answer anyway.

Comment: ReadAsync processes the XML stream in a background thread, while Read runs in the UI thread (here). While the peformance difference here may be neclectable, it is always a good idea to call the Async method equivalents if you are already in an awaitable method.

Answer (score 1):

My Final answer.

```
private async void btnQuickTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    await Task.Run(() => DoSomeWorkOnBgThread( (cnt) => //HAHA! this syntax is so confusing
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    txtRowCount.Text = cnt.ToString();
                }
            ); //end-invoke
        }
    ));

    MessageBox.Show("i am done!");
}


private void DoSomeWorkOnBgThread(Action<int> callbackFn)
{

    XmlReader reader;
    int rowCount = 0;
    using (reader = XmlReader.Create("someXmlFile.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rowCount++;

            DoMyProcessingHere();

            //only update UI every 100 loops
            if (rowCount % 100 == 0)
            {
                callbackFn(rowCount); ///
            }

        } //end-while
    }//end-using
}
```

Comment: It's better to use `IProgress<string>` with `Progress<string>` instead of `Dispatcher.Invoke`.